# Laravel making optional route parameter with segment

Tags: laravel

Here i would like to make optional parameter for `mobile_number` in this defined route:

```php
//Route:
Route::get('user-register/mobile_number={mobile_number?}', [UserAuthenticationController::class, 'register'])
    ->name('user-register');
```

```php
//UserAuthenticationController:
public function register (string $mobile_number=''): Renderable
{
    return view('user::register',compact('mobile_number'));
}
```

for opening both of `http://localhost/user-auth/user-register` and `http://localhost/user-auth/user-register/mobile-number=` i get `404 error`

how can i resolve this problem to have optional parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If url is

```
http://localhost/user-auth/user-register/98654
```

Your route should be

```
Route::get('user-register/{mobile_number?}', [UserAuthenticationController::class, 'register'])
    ->name('user-register');
```

if you are passing as query param then no need to mention in route

For example url is

```
 http://localhost/user-auth/user-register?mobile-number=
```

Then route will be

```
   Route::get('user-register', [UserAuthenticationController::class, 'register'])
            ->name('user-register');
```

and method

```
public function register (Request $request): Renderable
{
    $mobile_number=$request->{"mobile-number"};
    return view('user::register',compact('mobile_number'));
}
```